# Multiple Todo lists in Django

Tags: django

I am currently learning Django and as a starter Project, I thought of making a Todo List website.

I need help arranging the views to show multiple todo lists in a 
"title" : "text" kinda manner. 
eg: "June todo" : "1.Learn Django", "2.Create a Django App" etc

So far this is what I have done:

todo.html HTML:

```
<h1>Todo List!</h1>
<ul>
    {% for todo in all_items %}
        <li><a href="/todos/{{todo.id}}">{{todo.title}}</a>: {{todo.text}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

<form action="/addTodo/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <h3>Create New Todo List</h3>
    <input type="text" name="text", placeholder="Enter Title Here">
    <input type="Submit" name="Create">
</form>
```

models.py :

```
class SimpleTodo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    text = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.title)
```

views.py:

```
def TodoView(request):
    all_items = SimpleTodo.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/todo.html', {'all_items':all_items})
```

Current output:

```
Todo List!
- June: Todo List #1
- June: My first todo
- June: My second todo
- Aug: My First todo Aug
```

Expected Output:

```
Todo List!
- June: 
    Todo List 
    1 My first todo
    My second todo
- Aug: 
    My First todo Aug
```

PS: the goal is to kinda create a website such that people can share their todolists on a common newsfeed, would appreciate any help in that aspect as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's a book called [Test Driven Development with Pytho](https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/)n that does just that. It shows you test driven development using Django and the example project is a to-do list. Better yet you can read it for free on line and ask the author questions, and he is pretty quick to respond most of the time.

There is a lot to learn!

Comment: Thank you for sharing the resource. But could you possibly help me with the problem at hand for now?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a hierarchy, split the model into two like this (I left out the **str** methods to save space.

```
class SimpleTodo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

Class TodoText(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey(SimpleTodo)
    text = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

I don't think your view has to change. You would need to change your template to have nested for loops like.

```
<h1>Todo List!</h1>
<ul>
    {% for todo in all_items %}
        <li><a href="/todos/{{todo.id}}">{{todo.title}}</a></li>
             <ul>
             {% for text in todo.TodoText.all %}
                  <li>{{text.text}}</li>
             {% endfor %}
             </ul>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I've not tested this so there's probably a mistake somewhere, but hopefully this will lead you down the right path.